# Dependency injection asp.net n-tier c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am developing an N-tier application using asp.net core 3.1

- Application.Services
- Application.Domain
- Application.Data

In application.domain I would have to interface and one repository

- `IIntentRepository`, `IntentRepository`
- `IPredictionRepository`, `PredictionRepository`

In my data layer I would have 1 interface

- `IIntentDataRepository`, `IntentDataRepository`

In my startup.cs file I would then call each dependency injection like follow.

```
services.AddTransient<IIntentRepository,IntentRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IPredictionRepository,PredictionRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IIntentDataRepository,IntentDataRepository>();
```

Then I usually place the Interface in the constructor such as

```
        private readonly IIntentDataRepository intentDataRepsoitory;
        public IntentRepository(IIntentDataRepository _intentDataRepsoitory)
        {
            intentDataRepsoitory = _intentDataRepsoitory;
        }
```

The issues is in my `PredictionRepository` I would like to call `IntentRepository` in the domain layer. I am not sure how to do it, this is how I call it in my domain layer

```
    public class PredictionRepository : IPredictionRepository
    {
        private readonly IIntentRepository intentRepository;
        PredictionRepository(IIntentRepository _intentRepository)
        {
            intentRepository = _intentRepository;
        }
...}
```

But i keep getting `PredictionRepository` 'could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.)'

Comment: It looks like correct. Are you getting this error on runtime or build?

Comment: It is at runtime, here is the error more specific: System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:

Comment: "Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor" - 

PredictionRepository constructor is not marked as public. Could that be the culprit, or is it just a typo in your copy pasted code ?

Comment: @Larry i just updated the code, it was a class, and prediction is the constructor of the class, sorry for confusion

Comment: @Larry is right the class can be made private or internal, but the constructor should be public. (If I remember correctly.) When you do not provide an access modifier it is by default private

Comment: Please, give "public PredictionRepository(IIntentRepository _intentRepository)" a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception message looks accurate:

> ... Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all
> parameters of a public constructor.

Your pasted code shows that the `PredictionRepository` constructor is not marked as public, that's why the DI mechanism is not able to use it.